# Can a Liferay permissions resource represent an object outside of portal?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

The [Liferay Security and Permissions docs](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/security-and-permissio-4) define a Resource as:

> A generic term **for any object represented in the portal**. Examples of
>   resources include portlets (e.g. Message Boards, Calendar, etc.), Java
>   classes (e.g. Message Board Topics, Calendar Events, etc.), and files
>   (e.g. documents, images, etc.)

As described in another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367895/how-to-use-liferays-permission-system-in-other-applications), I'm considering trying to use Liferay's permission system in another application (not a portlet).

In my use case, Liferay resources would be defined for domain objects in my application.  When a new domain object is created in my application, I would add a corresponding new resource in Liferay (presumably by using the JSON-WS  API).

The docs also state:

> The name parameter is the fully qualified Java class name for the
>   resource object being added. The primKey parameter is the primary key
>   of the resource object.

Am I undertanding correctly that the 'name parameter' just has to match a`<model-name>` I've previously defined in a `<model-resource>`?

And the 'primKey parameter' doesn't have to match any particular object in the Portal database?  It could be a primary key of an object in my external database?

So, can a Liferay permissions resource represent an object outside of portal? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you describe it, it should work. Basically the liferay-resource-action definition does it all for you.

But 'name parameter' is not string. Its PK from CLASSNAME_ table, which contains all class names defined in liferay. Here you have to add a line which holds the full qualified java class name.

The 'primarKey' parameter is usually a primary key of some entity form liferay. So maybe you can keep the concept and set you entity pk in the field.